# Apply pivot on certain columns and get breakup of the columns along with the agregate value

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have a query which generates result set such as below image :

[image]

And i want  a result set like this

[image]

Along with the below pivoted columns

[image]

I have used the below query for pivot

```
select distinct
    ptbl.PdaId,
    ptbl.BusinessUnitName,
    ptbl.SalesAreaName,
    ptbl.regionName,
    ptbl.territoryName,
    ptbl.ResponseType,
    [11-04-2016],
    [11-17-2016],
    [11-18-2016],
    [11-20-2016] 
from 
    (select 
        #data.PdaId,
        #data.UserName,
        #data.BusinessUnitName,
        #data.SalesAreaName,
        #data.regionName,
        #data.territoryName,
        #data.ResponseType,
        #data.TOTAL [TOTAL],
        #data.TOTAL [DateBreakUpTOTAL],
        MyTable.InterviewedDate
    from 
        #data
        join #InProgressResponses 
            on #InProgressResponses.PdaId=#data.PdaId
        left join MyTable
            on MyTable.PdaId=#data.PdaId
    ) tbl1
pivot
(
    sum([DateBreakUpTOTAL]) 
    for InterviewedDate in ([11-04-2016], [11-17-2016], [11-18-2016], [11-20-2016])
) ptbl
```

but the break up data is null instead of dividing the above total count into their respective dates.

Assume #data has the dataset that i have depicted in first image.

and MyTable has the dates that i have mentioned in the pivot.

What is wrong with my query?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?  Often these require different solutions.  That's why it is recommended you don't double tag.

Comment: @destination-data sql server